Assumptions required with respect to distribution to satisfy a relation
Let $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \{-1,1\}^n$, and $\mathcal{D}$ a distribution on $\mathcal{X}$ ( on a $\sigma$ -algebra of $\mathcal{X}$).
Let $f : \mathcal{X} \to \{0,1\}$.
For $i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$, we define the function: $\phi_i: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}$ such that for $x = (x_1, \cdots, x_n)$, $\phi_i(x) = (x_1, \cdots, -x_i, \cdots x_n)$.
I'm interested in the following probability: $\underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[f(x) = 0, f(\phi_i(x)) = 1 |x_i = 1]$
For a fixed $i$, if I make the assumption that the distribution $\mathcal{D}$ is invariant by the function $\phi_i$, can I say the following:
$$\underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[f(x) = 0, f(\phi_i(x)) = 1 |x_i = 1] = \underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[f(x) = 0 |x_i = 1] \times \underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[f(x)= 1 |x_i = - 1]$$
Explanation:
With the assumption that the distribution $\mathcal{D}$ is invariant by the function $\phi_i$, $x$ and $\phi_i(x)$ are independent and identically distributed. Therefore, the events $f(x) = 0$ and $ f(\phi_i(x)) = 1$ are independent.
$$\underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[f(x) = 0, f(\phi_i(x)) = 1 |x_i = 1] = \underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[f(x) = 0 |x_i = 1] \times \underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[f(\phi_i(x))= 1 |\phi_i(x) = - 1]$$
Because of the assumption $x \sim \mathcal{D} \implies \phi_i(x) \sim \mathcal{D}$, we do the change of variable and get the result.
My question is:
1- Is this logic true?
2- Do I need further assumptions? It seems like my assumption is the same as i.i.d assumption between $(\cdot | x_i = - 1)$ and $(\cdot | x_i =1)$?
2- What does it mean when we say a distribution is invariant by the transformation $\phi_i$, does it mean both vectors and their transformation with the function $\phi_i$
should have the same probability mass?

Counterexample:
Let's take for the sake of simplicity $f : \mathcal{X} \to \{-1,1\}$, and $f(x)=x_ix_j$:
\begin{gather*}
\underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[f(x) = -1, f(\phi_i(x)) = 1 |x_i = 1] = \underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[x_ix_j = -1, -x_ix_j = 1 |x_i = 1] = \underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[x_j = -1 |x_i = 1]\\
\underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[f(x) = -1 |x_i = 1] \times \underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[f(x)= 1 |x_i = - 1]= \underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[x_j = -1 |x_i = 1] \times \underset{x \sim \mathcal{D}}{\mathbb{P}}[x_j = -1 |x_i = -1]
\end{gather*}
It would have to be $\mathbb{P}(x_i=x_j)=1$.
